# Can I combine these two C# functions into one?

Tags: c#, linq, function

I have the following:

```
    protected SelectList GetReferenceOptions(string pk)
    {
        var options = new SelectList(_reference.Get(pk)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(o => o.Order), "RowKey", "Value");
        return options;
    }

    protected SelectList GetReferenceOptions(string pk, string value)
    {
        var options = new SelectList(_reference.Get(pk)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(o => o.Order), "RowKey", "Value", value);
        return options;
    }
```

This looks like something I could combine into one but I am not sure how to handle the parameters. Can someone help me by explaining how I could do this?

Comment: What do the two constructors for SelectList look like?  Is value set to null in the first case?

Comment: If `SelectList` has two constructors for whether the value is there or not, then it seems sensible to keep the two overloads you have here.

Comment: Using `var options` + `return options` is bad for code. In the MSIL, it runs `strloc` followed by the function to pull the value back off the stack. Just use `return new ...`

Comment: Keeping them as overloads is the prefered. Using one with default values like PHP is not recommended.

Comment: The SelectList has two constructors. I assume I need to have two SelectList calls. That would be okay. I would just like to somehow have an optional parameter so I could call one or the other SelectList depending if I had an argument for value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If value is set to null in the first constructor you show then this would work:

```
protected SelectList GetReferenceOptions(string pk, string value = null)
{
    var options = new SelectList(_reference.Get(pk)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .OrderBy(o => o.Order), "RowKey", "Value", value);
    return options;
}
```

Comment: The `SelectList` constructor that does not consume `value` passes `(object)null` as the value of that argument to the overload, so this is the best answer since it is exactly equivalent (and the most parsimonious).

Comment: @KirkWoll, I like your use of the word parsiminious. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a default parameter like:

```
protected SelectList GetReferenceOptions(string pk, string value=null)
{
    var options = 
         value==null
             ? new SelectList(_reference.Get(pk)
               .AsEnumerable()
               .OrderBy(o => o.Order), "RowKey", "Value")
             : new SelectList(_reference.Get(pk)
               .AsEnumerable()
               .OrderBy(o => o.Order), "RowKey", "Value", value);
    return options;
}
```

And then simply combine the two functions into one by checking the default parameter for being `null`.

Comment: So with this if I call GetReferenceOptions("123") or GetReferenceOptions("123", "456") it would be okay?

Comment: I just tried this but it does not compile. I get errors around the semicolon on the first OrderBy line.  Error 3 ; expected and Error 2 Invalid expression term ':' Error 1 Syntax error, ':' expected

Answer (score 0):

You should keep both the methods and DRY them. That's more OOP. May be:

```
protected SelectList GetReferenceOptions(string pk)
{
    return GetReferenceOptions(pk, null);
}

protected SelectList GetReferenceOptions(string pk, string value)
{
    return new SelectList(_reference.Get(pk).OrderBy(o => o.Order), 
                          "RowKey", "Value", value);
}
```